# If $g(x) = g(y)$ implies $f(x) = f(y)$ and $g$ is surjective, there's $h$ such that $f(x) = h(g(x))$

Tags: abstract-algebra, functions, elementary-set-theory, factoring

> **Exercise.** Given sets $E$, $F$, $G$ and functions $g : E \to F$ surjective, and $f : E \to G$. Prove that there's a function $h : F \to G$ such that $f = h \circ g$ **if and only if** the equality $g\left(x\right) = g\left(y\right)$, with $x, y \in E$, implies the equality $f\left(x\right) = f\left(y\right)$.

My strategy was the following.

**Right to left.** I assume that $h$ exists. Then if $g(x) = g(y)$, $h(g(x)) = h(g(y))$. Therefore $f(x) = f(y)$ by definition.

**Left to right.** I assume that the equality $g(x) = g(y)$, with $x,y\in E$, implies the equality $f(x) = f(y)$. Given that $g$ is surjective, $g^{-1}(g(E)) = g^{-1}(F) = E$. Therefore $f(g^{-1}(g(x))) = f(x)$ [**Note**: I know that $f$ and $g$'s values at any given point $x\in E$ have the same preimages... but I don't know how to state this more formally.]. I can then define $h:\ F\ \longrightarrow\ G$ such that $h(x) = f\circ g^{-1}(x)$, and it verifies the stated condition.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof for right to left is good.

For left to right, note that $g^{-1}(g(E))=E$ for *any* function $g$, whether or not it is surjective. And because $g$ may not be injective, there is no such thing as $g^{-1}$ and so the expression
$$f(g^{-1}\circ g(x)),$$
is not well-defined. Similarly, the definition
$$h(x)=(f\circ g^{-1})(x),$$
is faulty because $g^{-1}$ need not exist.

---

In your note you seem to have the right idea; the fact that $g(x)=g(y)$ implies $f(x)=f(y)$ means that for every $z\in F$ and all $x,y\in g^{-1}(z)$ we have $f(x)=f(y)$, because
$$g(x)=z=g(y).$$
Note also that $g^{-1}(z)\subset E$ is non-empty because $g$ is surjective. This means
$$h(z):=f(x),\qquad\text{ where } x\in g^{-1}(z),$$
is a well-defined function $h:\ F\ \longrightarrow\ G$, and it clearly satisfies $f=h\circ g$.

Comment: Note: I think this uses axiom of choice to choose some $x\in g^{-1}(z)$ for every $z\in F$.

Comment: @palmpo No, it uses the surjectivity of $g$ for the existence of $x\in g^{-1}(z)$ for every $z\in F$.

Comment: $g^{-1}(z)$ is nonempty for every $z\in F$  by surjectivity, but I think we need a choice function $j:\mathcal{F}\to\bigcup\mathcal{F}$ where $\mathcal{F}=\{g^{-1}(z):z\in F\}$ to actually choose the $z$'s. Then $h(z)=f(j(g^{-1}(z)))$.

Comment: @palmpo We don't need to choose any $z$; for *every* $z\in F$ we define
$$h(z)=f(g^{-1}(z)).$$
We also don't need to choose any element of $g^{-1}(z)$; the above shows that $f(g^{-1}(z))$ is a singleton set for every $z\in F$. Then $h(z)$ is the unique element of $f(g^{-1}(z))$. This does not require the axiom of choice.

Comment: You are using $f(g^{-1}(z))$ as if $g^{-1}(z)$ refers to a unique inverse element, but $g^{-1}(z)=\{x\in E:g(x)=z\}$, which may not be singleton. It doesn't matter which element of $g^{-1}(z)$ we choose since for all $x,y\in g^{-1}(z)$, $g(x)=z=g(y)$ implies $f(x)=f(y)$, but we still have to choose some $x\in g^{-1}(z)$ for every $z\in F$ and hence AC is needed.

Comment: Oops in the comment before the previous comment, I meant "to actually choose the $x$'s in the $g^{-1}(z)$'s", not "to actually choose the $z$'s".

Comment: Indeed $g^{-1}(z)=\{x\in E:\ g(x)=z\}$ and similarly
$$f(g^{-1}(z))=\{f(x):\ g(x)=z\}=\{y\in G:\ (\exists x\in E)(g(x)=z\wedge f(x)=y)\},$$
is a well-defined set by the axiom schema of specification. By the given implication this is a singleton set, and we can define $h(x)$ to be its unique element.

Comment: I see now, if I understand correctly, $f(g^{-1}(z))$ is the *image* of $g^{-1}(z)$ under $f$, which is singleton, then we define $h(z)$ to be its unique element (and not the singleton set itself). Thanks for clarifying!